# Android Studio runs old version of project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried a lot.

I have connected my phone to the android studio to run the app onto. For some reason it will install and run the old version of the app. When I run the app on the emulator on the computer it works perfectly.

I have tried:

- Deleting the build folder
- Cleaning solution
- Rebuilding
- Copying the entire project into a new project, building it from scratch and rerunning it (still runs the old version of the other app).
- Praying to the coding gods.

Has anyone else had this issue?
All I want to do is run my app on my phone as I'm testing.

Comment: Looks like Tags in your question are not appropriate pls add appropriate tags only. How its related to IOS ?

Comment: Changed the tag.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the app data on the phone & uninstalling?